# "using" not working in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, using

I am new to MVC development.  I tried to move a class from one location to another in my solution, but after I made the new class one of `using` statements will no longer resolve.

The class that I moved was in this location xxx.Web.Business.ProjectTrack.NoticeDB.cs

The class the "using" is not working for is xxx.Web.Business.EmailNotice.EmailNotice.cs

The new class is xxx.Core.Business.NoticeDB.cs

The problematic using statement: using xxx.Web.Business.EmailNotice;

What can I do fix this problem?

Comment: Add the code, the class definitions and using's

Comment: Was it moved to a different project within the solution? If so does that different project have a reference to the project with the class it wants to use in it?

Comment: Assuming the namespacing is done correctly, I would guess that @JonHanna is correct.

Comment: what is a `developer XD`?

Comment: @Plutonix I edited that out, but my edit hasn't been approved yet.

Comment: Thanks! It does not have one. But -- A reference to xxx.Web would cause a circular dependency.

Comment: an emoticon of a smiley face...

Comment: I don't say this to be rude, but Stack Overflow questions probably aren't the place for `XD` faces

Comment: @fallingdog The circular dependency is the issue I address in my last paragraph of my answer.  Your `Core` package *really* probably should not depend on anything else.  That's why it's the "Core".

Comment: @Kyle Martin okay fair enough

Comment: More chat should probably take place here:  (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135910/discussion-between-kyle-martin-and-fallingdog).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that your `Core` project does not reference your `Web` project.

1. In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right-click on your `Core` project, hover `Add >`, click on `Reference`.
2. Drop down the `> Projects` tab on the left side.
3. Check your `Web` project checkbox.
4. Click `OK` to save.

That should take care of it.

The inner software architect in me, however, prompts me to ask:  Why is your `Core` project depending on your `Web` project?  Good development practices tell me that your `Core` project (if named correctly) probably shouldn't depend on any other project you have......  (not to mention the possibility of circular dependencies)

Comment: Thanks, Kyle - I bet they did not intend me to move the methods in the class that depend on Web.

Comment: I don't want to make false assumptions about how your application is set up, but that sounds like it would probably be a better idea than having `Core` depend on `Web`.

Answer (score 2):

If you've moved the class to a new project, that project may not contain the references required for those "using" statements. Under the new project, expand the "References" list and make sure that it contains similar references that the original project had.